# Синтаксис С++: описание конструктора

Tags: синтаксис, c++

Подскажите по синтаксису C++: разбираю исходники игры для дальнейшего дописания, столкнулся с неизвестной мне конструкцией в файле [GameLogic.cpp](http://codepad.org/4bUKwXYP) (его хедер [GameLogic.h](http://codepad.org/qXfpDgRI) ), так вот, после заголовка конструктора стоит "**:**". Правильно ли я понял, что сразу же происходит выполнение конструкторов соответствующих классов

```
GameLogic::GameLogic(QString mod, int countHumans, int coeffZombie, bool autoZombie)
: data(mod)
, motion(&data)
, attack(this, &data, &motion)
, intellect(this, &data, &motion)
, countHumans(countHumans)
, coeffZombie(coeffZombie)
, autoZombie (autoZombie)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это вызов конструкторов членов класса. Почитайте любую книжку по C++.

Comment: спасибо, книги я читал, но вот такого описания не видел.

Comment: Вызов конструкторов происходит в порядке, в котором члены класса объявлены в классе.

Answer (score 7):

Мейерс С. "Эффективное использование C++. 55 верных советов улучшить структуру и код ваших программ." (ISBN: `5-94074-304-8`) 41 страница:

```
ABEntry(const std::string & name, const std::string & address, const std::list < PhoneNumber > &phones)
{
    theName = name;     // все это присваивание, а не инициализация
    theAddress = address;
    thePhones = phones;
    numTimesConsulted = 0;
}
```

Лучший способ написания конструктора ABEntry – использовать список инициализации членов вместо присваивания.

```
ABEntry(const std::string& name, const std::string& address, const std::list<PhoneNumber>& phones)

:theName(name), // теперь это все – инициализации
 theAddress(address),
 thePhones(phones),
 numTimesConsulted(0)

{} // тело конструктора теперь пусто
```

Этот конструктор дает тот же самый конечный результат, что и предыдущий, но часто оказывается более эффективным. Версия, основанная на присваиваниях, сначала вызывает конструкторы по умолчанию для инициализации theName, theAddress и thePhones, а затем сразу присваивает им новые значения, затирая те, что уже были присвоены в конструкторах по умолчанию. Таким образом, вся работа конструкторов по умолчанию тратится впустую. Подход со списком инициализации членов позволяет избежать этой проблемы, поскольку аргументы в списке инициализации используются в качестве аргументов конструкторов для различных членов-данных. В этом случае theName создается конструктором копирования из name, theAddress – из address, thePhones – из phones. Для большинства типов единственный вызов конструктора копирования более эффективен – иногда намного более эффективен, чем вызов конструкторов по умолчанию с последующим вызовом операторов присваивания.