# Реализация класса с применением дружественной функции

Tags: c++builder, c++

```
#include <iostream.h>

class Point
{
    private int a, b;
    friend int T(Point a, Point b);
}

int T(Point a, Point b)
{
    return (a, b);
}

main()
{
    int a = 10, b = 11;
    cout << Point T(a, b);
    int vvod;
    cin >> n;
    return 0;
}
```

Где ошибка? Не хочет работать :(

Comment: Не совсем понятен вот эта реализация:

     int T(Point a, Point b)
     {
       return (a, b);
     }

Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Возвратить сразу два(!) объекта типа Point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного по Вашему коду:

- Отсутствует конструктор;
- Функция T возвращает некорректное значение (можно возвращать только одно значение).

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
    int x, y;
public:
    Point(int X, int Y):x(X), y(Y) {}

    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &stream, const Point obj);
};

ostream &operator << (ostream &stream, const Point obj) {
    stream << "X: " << obj.x << endl; 
    stream << "Y: " << obj.y << endl;
    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    Point A(10, 11);

    cout << A;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

---

А теперь по-моему коду:

- Добавил конструктор(не удивляйтесь, что он так оформлен, подробнее можете посмотреть тут [Синтаксис С++: описание конструктора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/99243/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0));
- Вместо функции T добавил перегрузку оператора <<;
- Добавил в конце программы getch(), для того чтобы увидеть результат.

Comment: Почему минус? Хотелось бы обоснования.

Comment: Возможно, это вам конькурент ножку подставил.

Answer (score 0):

На входе у нас объекты Point:
 1. Почему (a,b) - это int?
 2. T(a,b) - a,b, должны быть point не int

```
int T(Point a, Point b)
{
    return (a, b);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вообще непонятна вот эта реализация дружественного метода:

```
 int T(Point a, Point b)
 {
   return (a, b);
 }
```

Что вы вообще пытаетесь здесь сделать? Возвратить в функции, которая возвращает объект типа `int`, сразу два(!) объекта типа `Point` ? А хотя нееет, здесь вы, наверное, пытались возвратить две переменные типа `int` у одного из двух объектов класса( a и b ) наугад =)

---

Также вдребезги убило вот это определение:

```
  cout << Point T(a, b);
```

Что это вообще такое? Попытка вывести результат отработки конструктора?
Здесь можно наблюдать сразу две(!) ошибки. Первая( так себе ) заключается в том стандартные потоки ввода/вывода не сработают (I|O потоки), так как не включено пространство имен по умолчанию **std**. Вторая ошибка - вызов несуществующего конструктора:

```
Point(int aa, int bb):a(aa), b(bb) {}
```

---

И, наверное, последнее "недоразумение":

```
int vvod; // что определяем...
cin >> n;  // а считываем неопределенность.........
```

---

**P.S**   А по мне, так весь код - это сплошное недоразумение...